# Why the fonts are not displayed in GIF(flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, gif

I am making a move animation of text and i need to save it in GIF format, but why the standart text like Verdana font isn't displaying in GIF, in SWF its all ok

Comment: oh sorry its the animation that isn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

If font is not converting properly then make all the font outline before publish.